# Illegal String Offset - Using ACF in archive.php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using a custom function to pull custom post types that use WPs Categories into the same archive page as regular posts. The CPTs are loading with the correct text fields from ACF, but when I try to pull the image in using an array, I get and illegal string issue.

#### The custom function

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'properties'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

The code in question within the archive.

```
<?php
                $image = get_field('carousel_image');
                if( !empty($image) ):

                // vars

                $title = $image['title'];
                $alt = $image['alt'];

                // thumbnail
                $size = 'carousel-image';
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
                $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
                $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];

                ?>

                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block property-image" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />

            <?php endif; ?>

            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><small><?php echo the_field('town_and_county'); ?></small></a></h3>
```

I expected as usual that the image would be returned, but instead I'm getting:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 22 Warning: Illegal string offset 'alt' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 23 Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 27 Warning: Illegal string offset 'carousel-image' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 27 Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 28 Warning: Illegal string offset 'carousel-image-width' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 28 Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 29 Warning: Illegal string offset 'carousel-image-height' in /app/public/wp-content/themes/website-in-build/template-parts/content.php on line 29
```

A var_dump($image) returns

```
string(3) "125"
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: what $image = get_field('carousel_image'); returns?

Comment: What Roman said. Try `var_dump($image);` and share the output here (edit your question to include it, don't post it as a comment.)

Comment: in your custom fields setup, you probably have the image field return the ID, instead of it returning an array. - check that, and it should be fine

Comment: It's definitely setup to return an array. I'm using it elsewhere in the site and it's working fine. Only when trying to use it in the standard archive template does it do this.